# Messages not going to dead-letter queue on throwing exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have an application where I have to move the message to DLQ (dead-letter queue) on a particular case, but on the first message, the exception is thrown, but it ignores my max-attempts:2 value and I can see my exception message 4 times and the message has not gone to DLQ.

As mentioned in [spring cloud stream docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_dlq_dead_letter_queue), the message should go to DLQ on throwing an exception. When I try to send another message, I keep on getting a different exception in console logs until I restart the application to get first message again, but now the message goes to DLQ.

I tried using .onErrorContinue, in this case my application is not getting broken on first message, but messages are not going to DLQ.

EDIT:

There is an open incident on spring-cloud-stream repo for this issue
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1922

If anyone has any workaround to do retry, dead-letter-queue inside reactive function please provide an answer.

My application

```java
    @Bean
    public Function<Flux<String>, Flux<?>> processor() {
        return PaymentDetailsFlux -> PaymentDetailsFlux
//                .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(100000)))
                .flatMap(
                        paymentDetails -> {
                            throw new RuntimeException("intentional");

                            /* extracting payload from input */
//                        Map<Object, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();
//                        try {
//                            ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//                            payload = jsonMapper.readValue(paymentDetails, Map.class);
//                        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
//                            log.error("error while serializing input payload: "+paymentDetails);
//                            e.printStackTrace();
//                        }
//                        String message_id = (String) payload.get("message_id");
//                        log.info("<"+message_id+">"+" Received message from payment-supplier");
//                        log.info("<"+message_id+">"+" message payload: "+paymentDetails);
//
//                        /* DLQ if rule not found */
//                        if(!isValidateMAP(payload)){
//                            throw new RuntimeException("intentional");
////                            return Flux.error(new RuntimeException("<"+message_id+"> "+errMessage));
//                        }
//                            return Mono.just(paymentDetails);
                        }
                );
//                .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> {
//                    log.error(throwable.getMessage());
//                });
    }
```

my application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: payment-supplier
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: processor;ruleProcessor
    stream:
      bindings:
        processor-in-0:
          destination: processor-in     #input topic name
        processor-in-0.group: processor #queue name
        processor-out-0:
          destination: rule-in          #output topic name

        ruleProcessor-in-0:
          destination: ruleProcessor-in      #input topic name
        ruleProcessor-in-0.group: processor  #queue name
        #ruleProcessor-out-0:                #StreamBridge
      default-binder: rabbit

      #Defining DLQ - Dead Letter Queue
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          processor-in-0:
            consumer:
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              republish-to-dlq: true
              max-attempts: 2
              requeueRejected: true
              backOffInitialInterval: 900000
              backOffMaxInterval: 900000
            producer:
              autoBindDlq: true
              republishToDlq: true
              requeueRejected: true
              maxAttempts: 2
              backOffInitialInterval: 900000
              backOffMaxInterval: 900000


#Defining DLQ - Dead Letter Queue
#      rabbit:
        default:
          consumer:
            auto-bind-dlq: true
            republishToDlq : true
            maxAttempts : 3
            requeueRejected : true
#            backOffInitialInterval: 900000
#            backOffMaxInterval: 900000
          producer:
            auto-bind-dlq: true
            republishToDlq : true
            maxAttempts : 3
            requeueRejected : true
#            backOffInitialInterval: 900000
#            backOffMaxInterval: 900000
```

[image]
First message

```
2021-10-18 13:12:40.704 ERROR 6704 --- [-in.processor-1] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : Failed to invoke function 'processor'

java.lang.RuntimeException: intentional
    at com.gaic.paymentprocessor.service.PaymentProcessorService.lambda$processor$0(PaymentProcessorService.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.javaspringframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:374) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.5.4.jar:5.5.4]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:370) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.5.4.jar:5.5.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(Aborg.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-10-18 13:12:40.704 ERROR 6704 --- [-in.processor-1] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : Failed to convert output

java.lang.RuntimeException: intentional
    at com.gaic.paymentprocessor.service.PaymentProcessorService.lambda$processor$0(PaymentProcessorService.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1554) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:968) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:914) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1289) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2021-10-18 13:12:40.704 ERROR 6704 --- [-in.processor-1] onfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder : Failure was detected during execution of the reactive function 'processor'
2021-10-18 13:12:40.712 ERROR 6704 --- [-in.processor-1] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.RuntimeException: intentional
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: intentional
    at com.gaic.paymentprocessor.service.PaymentProcessorService.lambda$processor$0(PaymentProcessorService.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:386) ~[reactor-core-3.4.10.jar:3.4.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.10.jar:3.4.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.4.10.jar:3.4.10]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.10.jar:3.4.10]org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.4.jar:5.5.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.4.jar:5.5.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.4.jar:5.5.4]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.4.jar:5.5.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1300(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:69) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.5.4.jar:5.5.4]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:374) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.5.4.jar:5.5.4]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:370) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.5.4.jar:5.5.4]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1656) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1575) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1563) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1554) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:968) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:914) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1289) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

java.lang.RuntimeException: intentional
    at com.gaic.paymentprocessor.service.PaymentProcessorService.lambda$processor$0(PaymentProcessorService.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:386)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
    at reactor.core.publisher.UnicastManySinkNoBackpressure.tryEmitNext(UnicastManySinkNoBackpressure.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.IntegrationReactiveUtils.lambda$adaptSubscribableChannelToPublisher$8(IntegrationReactiveUtils.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1300(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:374)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:370)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1656)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1575)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1563)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:968)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:914)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1289)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Second message logs

```
2021-10-18 12:57:25.422 ERROR 9928 --- [-in.processor-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'payment-supplier.processor-in-0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[1330], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=processor-in, amqp_deliveryTag=2, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=processor-in.processor, amqp_redelivered=false, id=368d916d-af66-24c1-59c1-491d5dbc6dfa, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-fibQI2iMkG5_giNWmMMwlA, sourceData=(Body:'[B@1d04b729(byte[1330])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=processor-in, receivedRoutingKey=, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-fibQI2iMkG5_giNWmMMwlA, consumerQueue=processor-in.processor]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1634542042374}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[1330], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=processor-in, amqp_deliveryTag=2, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=processor-in.processor, amqp_redelivered=false, id=368d916d-af66-24c1-59c1-491d5dbc6dfa, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-fibQI2iMkG5_giNWmMMwlA, sourceData=(Body:'[B@1d04b729(byte[1330])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=processor-in, receivedRoutingKey=, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-fibQI2iMkG5_giNWmMMwlA, consumerQueue=processor-in.processor]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1634542042374}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:208)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$1300(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.lambda$onMessage$0(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:374)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:370)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1656)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1575)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1563)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:968)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:914)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1289)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[1330], headers={amqp_receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, amqp_receivedExchange=processor-in, amqp_deliveryTag=2, deliveryAttempt=3, amqp_consumerQueue=processor-in.processor, amqp_redelivered=false, id=368d916d-af66-24c1-59c1-491d5dbc6dfa, amqp_consumerTag=amq.ctag-fibQI2iMkG5_giNWmMMwlA, sourceData=(Body:'[B@1d04b729(byte[1330])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=processor-in, receivedRoutingKey=, deliveryTag=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-fibQI2iMkG5_giNWmMMwlA, consumerQueue=processor-in.processor]), contentType=application/json, timestamp=1634542042374}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I have answered the question in the Github (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1922), here is the answer

Hi @vishalmamidi,

I have implemented my own version of DLQ by using StreamBridge, basically, you need to implement the `onErrorNext` and send your message to DLQ via StreamBridge and then return `Mono.empty()`, just bear in mind you need to use `onErrorStop()` to prevent any strange behaviour with your up/down stream errors so it will make sure the error goes to `onErrorNext` not to `onErrorContinue`. Here is the code snippet I used

```
@Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty("app.reader.writerTest.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    fun writerTest(
        streamBridge: StreamBridge
    ) = Function<Flux<Message<TestReaderRequest>>, Mono<Void>> { item ->
        item
            .map {
                println("TEST: $it")
                it
            }
            .flatMap { request ->
                Mono
                    .just("Service Test")
                    .map {
                        throw Exception("Testing DLQ")
                    }
                    .handleDlq(request, streamBridge, logger, 1)
            }
            .then()
    }

fun <T> Mono<T>.handleDlq(request: Message<*>, streamBridge: StreamBridge, logger: Logger, retryThreshold: Int = 1) =
    onErrorResume { exception -> handleDlq<T>(request, retryThreshold, streamBridge, logger, exception) }
        .onErrorStop()

fun <T> Flux<T>.handleDlq(request: Message<*>, streamBridge: StreamBridge, logger: Logger, retryThreshold: Int = 1) =
    onErrorResume { exception -> handleDlq<T>(request, retryThreshold, streamBridge, logger, exception) }
        .onErrorStop()

private fun <T> handleDlq(
    request: Message<*>,
    retryThreshold: Int,
    streamBridge: StreamBridge,
    logger: Logger,
    exception: Throwable
): Mono<T> {
    logger.error(
        "Unable to finish the operation of request: $request due to: ",
        exception
    )
    val receivedTopic = request.headers[RECEIVED_TOPIC]
    val attempts = request.headers[DELIVERY_ATTEMPT, AtomicInteger::class.java] ?: AtomicInteger(1)
    val topic = if (attempts.get() < retryThreshold) {
        attempts.incrementAndGet()
        logger.info("About to retry the message of $request for topic: $receivedTopic, attempt #${attempts.get()} from $retryThreshold")
        receivedTopic.toString()
    } else {
        // TODO: needs to find the dlq name from application.yml
        val dlq = receivedTopic.toString() + "-dlq"
        logger.info("About to send the message of $request to dlq: $dlq after retrying ${attempts.get()} time(s)")
        dlq
    }
    val message = MessageBuilder
        .fromMessage(request)
        .setHeaders(buildRetryOrDlqMessageHeaders(request, attempts, topic, exception))
        .build()

    streamBridge.send(topic, message)
    return Mono.empty()
}

private fun buildRetryOrDlqMessageHeaders(
    request: Message<*>,
    attempts: AtomicInteger,
    topic: String,
    exception: Throwable
): MessageHeaderAccessor {
    val messageHeaders = MessageHeaderAccessor(request)

    messageHeaders.setHeader("spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination", topic)
    messageHeaders.setHeader(DELIVERY_ATTEMPT, attempts)
    messageHeaders.setHeader(DLT_ORIGINAL_TOPIC, request.headers[RECEIVED_TOPIC])
    messageHeaders.setHeader(DLT_EXCEPTION_FQCN, exception.javaClass.name)
    messageHeaders.setHeader(DLT_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, exception.message)
    messageHeaders.setHeader(DLT_EXCEPTION_STACKTRACE, exception.stackTraceToString())

    return messageHeaders
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions, hope it helps